# useEffect isn't executed when prop changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-effect

I have a component that get props from a class instance. When the user updates an input, it should update the class properties.

I was expecting that when the class instance is updated, it would trigger useEffect because the prop was changed, but it doesn't happen.

any idea why? is it because I'm sending the class as prop and not the class attributes?

SqlSchema.jsx

```
//this component should update the "connectionParams" class property
const SqlSchema = ({ sqlConnection }) => {
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
    //useEffect isn't triggered after executing "setConnection"
    useEffect(() => console.log(sqlConnection.connectionParams), [sqlConnection.connectionParams]);

    const setConnection = (params) => {
      sqlConnection.setConnection(params);
    };
    
    const stepContent = [
      <ConnectToDB data={sqlConnection.connectionParams} onChange={setConnection} />,
    ];
    
    return (
      <div className="sql-schema">
          <Typography>{stepContent[activeStep]}</Typography>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Router.jsx

```
//here I'm passing the class to the component
<Route path="/create-from-sql"><SqlSchema sqlConnection={SqlConnection} /></Route>
```

SqlConnection.js

```
class SqlConnection {
    connectionParams = {};

    setConnection(params) {  
        this.connectionParams = params;
    }
}

export default new SqlConnection();
```

Comment: you are sending new connection every time u refresh, is this really the behavior u want? It doesn't call because the params is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Why you don't store `connectionParams` in a `useState`? This way you can pass them and rerender correctly.

```
const [connectionParams, setConnectionParams] = useState({});

return <SqlSchema connectionParams={connectionParams} setConnectionParams={setConnectionParams} />
```

---

You are creating a new connection of every render of the Parent `sqlConnection={new SqlConnection()}`.
Try creating the connection on mount and then pass the variable to the child.

Comment: How the `SqlSchema` will know that params have changed and should re-render?

Comment: because sqlConnection prop have changed @kinduser

Comment: But changing ref object doesnt trigger the re-render.

Comment: I have a lot of logic to do in the class (I put only the relevant code here) regarding the sql connection and make in in a class would help me to avoid duplicate actions and iterations by saving an intermediate results in every step in the sqlSchema

Comment: You may have the logic for sql connection in separate functions and if connectionParams are needed you can pass them to any sql connection function. But having the props in a state is best way to manage the rerender of the child component. You also may pass the state to the object with `new SqlConnection(conParams);`

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `SqlConnection` won't trigger component update when the `connectionParams` update within the class. You'd have to somehow subscribe to the `connectionParams` changes. Example below passes the state *setter* to the `SqlConnection` class, so when the params are updated, the state change is triggered, the `useEffect` is now able to listen to the `params` change and now you are able to use them and set the sql connection with proper params.

```js
class SqlConnection {
  stateSetter;
  
  constructor(setter) {
    this.stateSetter = setter;
  }
  
  connectionParams = {};

  setConnection(params) {  
    this.connectionParams = params;
    this.stateSetter(this.connectionParams);
  }
}

const SqlSchema = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({});
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = new SqlConnection(setValue);
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log('Current params - ', value); // do stuff with params
  }, [value]);

  const setParams = () => {
    ref.current.setConnection({ foo: 'bar' });
  };

  return <div>
    <button onClick={setParams}>Update params</button>
    {JSON.stringify(value)}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<SqlSchema />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```